# php кодировка в терминале Windows

Tags: php, windows, кодировка, cmd, терминал

Есть php обработчик, который выполняет в цикле `exec` команды вида

`exec(icacls "\\\\10.0.7.41\\project\\1111_Проект\\01_Подраздел\\19.09.2018_альбом" /inheritance:e /T, $systemMessage);`

> Кодировка файла скрипта utf8 без BOM

В цикле перебирается около сотни папок.
Результаты выполнения в помещаю в systemMessage.
Подскажите как правильно работать с кодировкой в которой windows возвращает `$systemMessages`, 
Пример того что я получаю выполняя в командной строке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот что я получаю когда пытаюсь вывести данные на экран в браузере или записать в файл логов

```
foreach ($systemMessages as $message){
            echo $message;
            file_put_contents($fileName , $message . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        }
```

На экране:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вроде бы все хорошо, но когда заглядываешь в файл, там:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать с элементом $message в массиве $userMessages, что бы он корректно записался в файл?

```
Пробовал iconv("windows-1251","utf-8",$message)
```

не помогает.

Comment: дак там не 1251 возвращается, видимо

Comment: @teran а что возвращается?))

Comment: на koi8r похоже, или в командной строке обычно cp866 обычно по умолчанию. Можно перед вызовом exec сменить локаль на нужную

Comment: cp866 подошел, спасибо.